# Schneider setting position of servo with Codesys

Tags: servo, codesys

I am trying to set to position of a Schneider `LXM52 servo` with a `PacDrive` using `Codesys`.  I have tried using the `SetPosition` function block but that is not setting the position in the drive through a power cycle of the drive.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FC_SetposSingle or its equvilent will not persist through a power cycle. You need to use FB_WriteDriveEncoder. the Function Block is found in the standard PDL library.